# Na values in rankings

Tags: correlation, ranking

Having a table of rankings containing many Na values, how should I deal with Na values while calculating the correlation between those rankings?

Comment: NA values mean that there's no data for these cases, so there's no way at all. Nobody can say whether a NA value is higher or lower than some other value, so correlation simply cannot be calculated on those cases.

Comment: Thank you @Erwan for answering! so, should I drop the lines that have a NA value so I don't have errors while calculating the correlation?

Comment: Yes, this is the only way. But you might want to check the proportion of NA values as well, because if this proportion is high it's not sure that the correlation score is representative.

Comment: Thank you so much @Erwan for your help!